# Разница между атрибутами datetime и pubdate

Tags: html, html5

Вообщем верстаю блог, и столкнулся с такой проблемой. При указании даты публикации поста использую тег time. Так вот у [него](http://htmlbook.ru/html/time) есть два атрибута datetime и pubdate. Но в чем разница немогу понять. И который следует использовать?

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/time

http://htmlbook.ru/html/time/datetime

http://htmlbook.ru/html/time/pubdate

Также с атрибутом **`pubdate`** код не проходит проверку через валидатор

Выдает ошибку "Error: Attribute pubdate not allowed on element time at this point".

Comment: Перед тем, как задавать этот вопрос, я предварительно прочитал про эти атрибуты. И если бы, я понял, то не задавал бы этот вопрос. 
datetime - задает дату, время или оба значения для текста.
pubdate - указывает дату публикации документа.
По сути написано одно и тоже, указывает на время публикации документа, или что-то не так?